# How to retrieve the name of the arguments passed in a function using Decorators

Tags: python, parameters, decorator

```
import sys
def entryExit(f):
    def new_f(self,*args):
        print "Entering", f.__name__,self.__class__.__name__ 
        f(self,*args)
        print "Exited", f.__name__,self.__class__.__name__
    return new_f


class A:
    @entryExit
    def move(self,g,h):
        print "hello"
        print g,h           

a=A()
a.move(5,7)
```

The above code outputs

```
Entering move A
hello
5 7
Exited move A
```

I was able to retrieve the method name as well as the class in which it is define using decorators. But i wasnt able to retrieve the name of the method parameters during runtime.

Basically i need an output like this

```
Entering move A g,h
hello
5 7
Exited move A g,h
```

So what should i add in the print statements to get an output like above.

Thank you

Comment: All you are doing with your print statement is printing the method name and class name, you aren't telling it print your parameters `g, h`

Comment: @PurityLake -- I think that OP wants to know how to figure out that the arguments are named `g` and `h`

Comment: FYI, `self` is redundant and actually makes your decorator less flexible in this case.  Just have `(*args, **kwargs)` on the wrapper; the implicit `self` will be unpacked correctly when needed for instance methods, but you don't force all methods that the decorator is used on to have at least one argument any more.

Comment: @sr2222 -- I'm kind of surprised that there isn't something in the standard library (`functools` maybe?) which would transform the call signature of the function...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`inspect.getargspec`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) for this.

e.g.:

```
import sys
import inspect
def entryExit(f):
    def new_f(self,*args):
        print "Entering", f.__name__,self.__class__.__name__,inspect.getargspec(f).args[1:]
        f(self,*args)
        print "Exited", f.__name__,self.__class__.__name__
    return new_f


class A:
    @entryExit
    def move(self,g,h):
        print "hello"
        print g,h           

a=A()
a.move(5,7)
```

results in:

```
Entering move A ['g', 'h']
hello
5 7
Exited move A
```